# Magento-2 override template for Group product in my module

Tags: magento2, grouped-products

I am using magento-2.0.0 . I am trying to overtire

`vendor/magento/module-grouped-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml` with my module template.

My module layout code of

`frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.grouped">
            <action method='setTemplate'>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Modulename::availability.phtml</argument>
            </action>           
        </referenceBlock>        
    </body>
</page>
```

Default file code `/vendor/magento/module-grouped-product/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="page-product-grouped"/>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">
            <block class="Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped" name="product.info.grouped" before="product.info.addtocart" template="product/view/type/grouped.phtml"/>
            <container name="product.info.grouped.extra" after="product.info.grouped" before="product.info.grouped" as="product_type_data_extra" label="Product Extra Info"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.grouped.extra">
            <block class="Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Stockqty\Type\Grouped" template="Magento_CatalogInventory::stockqty/composite.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>

        <referenceContainer name="product.info.type">

          <!-- below block i am trying to overrite-->

            <block class="Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped" as="product.info.grouped" template="product/view/type/default.phtml"/>

        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

My problem is there is no name attribute alias is `as="product.info.grouped"` . Alias is already used  in above code.

```
<block class="Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped" name="product.info.grouped" before="product.info.addtocart" template="product/view/type/grouped.phtml"/>
```

So My template render at `product/view/type/grouped.phtml` instead of `product/view/type/default.phtml`

I can able to give different name attribute and use it in my module.But I am developing extension .
Is it magento bug? 
Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added below code to my layout file

frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>        
         <referenceContainer name="product.info.type">
                <block class="Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped" template="Namespace_Modulename::group-available.phtml" />             
         </referenceContainer>  
    </body>
</page>
```

It is working for me.May be it helpful to other.

Comment: amazing thanks this solved my issue as well. I am wondering though is that the right way??

Answer (score 4):

This is what I end up doing to override the `vendor/magento/module-grouped-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml` template from `Magento_GroupedProduct` module.

Created new layout file `catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml` at location `Namespace/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.grouped">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Module::catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit your layout file as below:

In your Module `frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="product.info.type">
                <block class="Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped" as="product.info.grouped" template="Namespace_Modulename::availability.phtml"/>

            </referenceContainer>      
        </body>
    </page>
```

Also update your system as magento 2.0 is having many bugs.

Not in this issue but it may cause errors sometime somewhere as 2.0 is unstable version.

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score -2):

For overwriting a phtml file of a module you must put the file in Magento_Modulename/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml.