# Magento 2: unable to override product/view/addtocart.phtml from my module

Tags: magento2, module, layout, template

I am trying to customize the `product/view/addtocart.phtml` template in my extension. I was already able to customize other templates but for this one it just won't work.

I found the template is defined in

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml
```

among much more XML is this bit:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info" template="product/view/form.phtml" after="alert.urls">
                <container name="product.info.form.content" as="product_info_form_content">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
                </container>
```

I know the XML which determines what template is loaded for the "**product.info.addtocart**". Because if I change the template of in this XML to template

```
MyNamespace_MyModule::product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

It successfully overrides the template with my own. However of course I need to do this from within my module. I already tried many ways but not matter what I try it has no effect...

Among other things I have created a file

```
app\code\MyNamespace\MyModule\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml
```

and put the following code in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">MyNamespace_MyModule::product/view/addtocart.phtml</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
<referenceContainer name="content" remove="true">
</layout>
```

and it has no effect. Interestingly notice the

```
<referenceContainer name="content" remove="true">
```

that should actually blank the page but it does nothing either (if I put the same XML bit in the `Magento_Catalog` `catalog_product_view.xml` then it effectively blanks the page..).

So I assume the problem is not that my code is not good  but rather that my whole layout XML is not being read for some reason... I thought maybe I had a permission problem so just to be sure I chmoded the whole Module directory at 777 but still my layout XML has no effect...

How come I am unable to override anything, why is my

```
app\code\MyNamespace\MyModule\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml
```

having no effect?? Could it have something to do with the order of loading the modules?

If yes how come I am able to overide other layout XML from the Magento Catalog module from the same module such as

```
app\code\MyNamespace\MyModule\view\base\layout\catalog_product_prices.xml
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Try to run php bin/magento setup:upgrade command, remove cache

Answer (score 8):

Well I was finally able to find an answer thanks to this very site:

I found my answer here: [Magento-2 override template for Group product in my module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109017/magento-2-override-template-for-group-product-in-my-module)

Basically to resume it turns out somehow my XML must not have been good. Inspired by one of the answers from the above link I changed my `app/code/MyNamespace/MyModule/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` code to

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>        
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="MyNamespace_MyModule::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>  
    </body>
</page>
```

and that worked!!!!

Answer (score 5):

Steps to override the `addtocart.phtml`

1.Copy `addtocart.phtml` file from

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

And paste this file in your module

E.g.

> app/code/CompanyName/Mymodule/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

2.Now Create `catalog_product_view.xml` file in your module `app/code/CompanyName/Mymodule/view/frontend/layout/`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">CompanyName_Mymodule::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
         </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

3.Do whetever you want to change in `addtocart.phtml`

4.Run below Command Line on your Magento 2 root directory

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 3):

Create `catalog_product_view.xml` file in your module `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/` and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>  
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>                         
    </body>
</page>
```

Create `addtocart.phtml` file in your module `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/view` and add your code here

```
<?php echo "addtocart.phtml file overite"  ?>
```

then flush cash using command or in admin cache management

```
php bin/magento c:f
```

same solution working for me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To override addtocart.phtml template file in your module use below code

1. Create file catalog_product_view.xml in the directory path
   Vendor_Module/view/frontend/layout and add below code.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>        
           <referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">
               <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="Vendor_Module::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
           </referenceContainer>  
       </body>
   </page>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps-

1. Create your module
2. Copy file from

vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

To

app/code/MyNamespace/MyModule/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

Make your change in this file

3. Create layout file

app/code/Kh/CustomOption/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

code is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">MyNamespace_MyModule::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>

    </body>
</page>
```

4. Clear the cache - bin/magento cache:clean